# Why dependent variables are defined to be scalars in definition of linear regression

Tags: regression, definition

I was reading about *linear regression* on wikipedia. It was defined as an approach for modeling the relationship between a **scalar** dependent variable $y$ and one or more explanatory variables. Later on as I proceeded with my reading on wiki, I couldn't find any relevant statement which precisely deals with the fact of the dependent variable being scalar as a necessary condition for defining the concept of linear regression. In fact, in one of the extensions of L.R. called *General linear models* , $y$ is not a scalar but a vector.

So my question is why do we define $y$ as a scalar in the main definition? Even if we skip the scalar part, what difference does it make?

Comment: When $y$ is a vector (with a finite number of dimensions greater than $1$) it is called *multivariate* linear regression, that's all.

Comment: Dark_Knight  -- Be careful of the distinction in multiple linear regression between the scalar $y_i$ (the $i$th response is a single value) and the vector $\mathbf{y}$ -- the entire set of $y_i,\, i=1,2,...,n$ being stacked up to write the equations in matrix form.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, it's just an arbitrary definition, at least for simple and multi*variable* linear regression. It's not that you *can't* have a dependent vector, it's that we call regressions with a dependent vector multi*variate* linear regression.

Answer (score 0):

$Y$ is generally not a scalar. But in normal linear regression, a usual assumption is that the observations $Y$ are independent, homoskedastic(the distribution of each $Y$ have the same variance) and normally distributed with a mean that depends on the value of the covariates $X_1, X_2, ..., X_p$. Thus the relationship between $Y$ and $X$ is the same for all indices of $Y$,  one could also define the linear model as $Y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1X_{1i} + ...\beta_pX_{pi} + \epsilon_{i}$. Here $\mathbf{Y} = (Y_1, ..., Y_n)$ is clearly a vector.